# Meaning of "Beitrag zum Büfett"

Tags: meaning

I came across the sentence

> Über einen kleinen Beitrag zum Büfett würde ich mich freuen!

What does this sentence mean? What is a "contribution to the buffet"? Is it saying like "I would be delighted if you could bring some food to buffet"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty much, yes. It politely asks for a small contribution to the food (at a party, we suppose, or other such occasion.)

Comment: Thanks, it helps that you said "at a party" because I was pretty much thinking about buffet at a restaurant.

Answer (score 4):

Just would like to add: depending on the context, it could also mean a financial contribution. For example if there is a wedding at a fancy restaurant, I doubt you're expected you to bring a bowl of potato salad.

So if in doubt: ask, what you could contribute. That's how I usually do it. This also avoids the situation of having five potato salads or the like.